# Replace fieldset on button click

Tags: javascript, fieldset

I'm trying to make a page in which I have two fieldsets, using javascript I want to make the 2nd fieldset not shown till I click "Next" button, and then the 1st fieldset become not shown also I want the "Next" button to be changed to an input submit so here is my code

```
<fieldset id="1">
       ...
</fieldset>
<fieldset id='2' style="display:none;">
       ...
</fieldset>
<div>
   <input class="cancel" type="reset" name="Cancel" value="Annuler"/>
   <button id="4" class="ok" onclick="myFunction()" >Next</button>
   <input  id="3" class="ok" type="submit" value="Done" style="display:none;" />
</div>

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("1");
    var y = document.getElementById("2");
    var z = document.getElementById("3");
    var a = document.getElementById("4");

    y.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "none";   
    a.style.display = "none";
```

}

But when I click the "Next" button, the 2nd fieldset become shown and then back to the 1st fieldset, the button not changed at all. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: already working : https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/942/

Comment: When adding the rest of the code i get {"error":"key missing: title"}
https://jsfiddle.net/theAN10/r4zpjne5/9/

Comment: Not sure what you mean, should work https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/r4zpjne5/13/

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/p19h45ot/)**.

Make sure you're placing your function at the top inside the `head` tag then it should work, else you'll get :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("1");
  var y = document.getElementById("2");
  var z = document.getElementById("3");
  var a = document.getElementById("4");
  y.style.display = "block";
  z.style.display = "block";
  x.style.display = "none";
  a.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="1">
  ...1
</fieldset>
<fieldset id='2' style="display:none;">
  ...2
</fieldset>
<div>
  <input class="cancel" type="reset" name="Cancel" value="Annuler" />
  <button id="4" class="ok" onclick="myFunction()">Next</button>
  <input id="3" class="ok" type="submit" value="Done" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

**NOTE:** You need to add the `type="button"` to the button to prevent the submit.

Answer (score 0):

An id must be unique to an element. You have multiple elements with the same id, which will cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: i changed it to "3" ,added a z var for submit input,  but nothing happened

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. As it stands, your code should successfully hide the first fieldset and button, then show the second fieldset and button. Are you looking for the second button to do something? because right now there's no JS hooked up to it.